# where do I set Azure ServiceBus timeout

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

The default setting for this is 60 seconds but I need to adjust this to 30.   I create all of my messages by doing the following:

```
 public void SendMessage<T>(T message)
        {
            string conn = "Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString." + message.GetType().Name;
            string queueName =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[message.GetType().Name + "QueueName"];
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[conn];
            QueueClient Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
            var m = new BrokeredMessage();
            m.Properties["body"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            Client.Send(m);
        }
```

Where in here can I set the timeout for sending a message to ServiceBus?  Currently Service Bus is down so this is causing me real issues :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the timeout by using MessagingFactorySettings:

```
        Uri serviceBusUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "[serviceNamespace]", string.Empty);

        MessagingFactorySettings factorySettings = new MessagingFactorySettings()
        {
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("[keyName]", "[sharedAccessKey]"),
            OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        };

        MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(serviceBusUri, factorySettings);
        QueueClient Client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("[QueueName]");
```